# Swift Spritekit count touches

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to have several actions on one node.

so for example on the first touch on this node, the first action should run. On the second touch: the second action should run.

below a not working example of the code with touches.count.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node == myNode {
            if touches.count == 1 {
                action1()
            }
            if touches.count == 2 {
                action2()
            }
            if touches.count == 3 {
                action3()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a member variable that tracks the number of touches since your app started up. The method touches.count isn't cumulative.

```
var cumulativeNumberOfTouches = 0

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node == myNode {

            cumulativeNumberOfTouches += 1

            switch cumulativeNumberOfTouches {
            case 1:
                action1()
            case 2:
                action2()
            case 3:
                action3()
            default:
                /* do something or nothing or whatever */
                println("\(cumulativeNumberOfTouches) touches")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of count you want to use touches.tapCount. This detects the taps you are doing and should register 1, 2 and 3 (taps are fast so you have to tap fast).

EDIT: Do you mean how many times someone taps the screen or do you mean how many fingers are on the screen at once?

Comment: tapCount isnt the solutions as well. This counts the number of counts during one "touch phase"
I am looking for something that counts the total touches since the app was startet.